# How to change text Cancel button Searchbar of iPhone in Titanium?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, titanium

When I set the value 'true' to showCancel property in the method Titanium.UI.createSearchBar. It displays me the cancel button, but I would like to customize that button text to Go or anything else. How do I do that? Please give me suggestions. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in Titanium Mobile SDK 1.4 you can change the button text.

As a work around you could add your own button to the screen and have it interact with the tableview.  Not an ideal solution though.

Please find below the current documentation link.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.SearchBar-object